# Produce all unordered unique combinations of N-sized subsets of an m·N-sized set

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

Say there is a set of *m*·*N* named elements. How to produce all the (unordered) combinations of *N*-sized subsets?

For example, *m*=2 and *N*=2, the elements are called A, B, C and D. There will be 3 combinations: AB+CD, AC+BD and AD+BC.

For *m*=2 and *N*=3 there will be 10 combinations. In general, it will be:

$$\frac{(mN)!}{(N!)^m\cdot m!}$$

([thanks](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4111079/699405) to Ross Millikan)

How to approach creating an algorithm that produces / iterates over the whole set of combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is **[a program in Java](https://replit.com/@Apass_Jack/cs139262produceAllUnorderedUniqueCombinationsOfNSizedSubset)** that prints all unordered unique `m`-combinations of `N`-sized subsets of numbers from 0 inclusive to `m * N` exclusive. Click the run button to see some result.

---

The algorithm used in the program is adapted from the usual algorithm that produces all unique $k$-combinations out of $U$ objects. Here is some explanation of the recursive method, `static void printCombinations(int m, final int N, int startNumber, boolean[] used, int[][] subsetsHolder, int curSubset, int toFill)`.

That method prints all print all unordered partition of numbers starting from 0 inclusive to `m * N` exclusive into `m` subsets of size `N`, where

- the first `curSubset` subsets have been specified by `subsetsHolder[0:curSubset]` and
- the first `N - toFill` numbers in the current subset, `subsetsHolder[curSubset]` have been specified in `subsetsHolder[curSubset][0:N - toFill]` and
- if `toFill` is not `N`, all unspecified numbers in `subsetsHolder[curSubset]` must be at least `startNumber`. If it is `N`, the first number in `subsetsHolder[curSubset]` must be the first unused number.

The parameter `used` records those specified numbers. Namely, `used[i]` is true iff `i` has been specified somewhere. It is a convenience argument to ease the coding.

---

The body of that method is, in fact, quite simple, thanks to the power of recursion.

It first checks if all `N` numbers of the current subset is waiting to be selected.

- If yes, there are two cases.

  - If `curSubset` is `m`, we have arrive at a full combination. Print and return.
  - Else we will find the smallest unused number. It becomes the `0`-th element of the current subset, i.e., `subsetsHolder[curSubset][0]`. Recurse to fill the next number in the current subset.
- Otherwise,

  - If there is no more to fill the current subset, recurse to fill the next subset.
  - Else let the next smallest number in the current subset to iterate through all numbers starting at `startNumber`. Recurse to fill the next number in the current subset.

---

It is not hard to prove that the algorithm/program prints all wanted combinations once in the natural lexicographic order.

Comment: Here is [an implementation in Python 3](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/vasNPZuct3).

Answer (score 2):

Knuth wrote a [chapter](http://www.kcats.org/csci/464/doc/knuth/fascicles/fasc3a.pdf) on this, as part of the new volume 4 of his Art of Computer Programming.

The simplest algorithm uses the following recursion to generate all combinations of length $m$ of a set $x_1,\ldots,x_n$:

- If $m = 0$ then output the empty set.
- Otherwise, for each $m \leq i \leq n$, generate all combinations of length $m-1$ of $x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1}$, and add $x_i$ to all of them.